# Remove Old Moen Kitchen Faucet

Tags: faucet

Need to remove an old faucet head that I cannot find a similar one anywhere. Don’t know if it helps but there’s a screw on top of the faucet as well. But this is what underneath looks like, have no idea what I’m supposed to be unscrewing as it looks like nothing it keeping the faucet attached to the sink[image]

Comment: The two 15/16 brass nuts are pulling the faucet head onto the deck of your sink.  you want a basin wrench or crow foot to remove them.

Answer (score 4):

Moen was the dramatic stepchild of faucets for a bit.  This looks like its rebellious phase right before the "U-clamps".  Image shows order:

[image: Order of Removal]

First remove your water connection.  Next use a basin wrench to loosen nut # 2.  Go to the top-side and loosen the retaining ring at the base of the faucet (If there is one).  Then go back below and loosen Nut # 3.

If everything checks out, you should be able to unscrew # 2 and 3 and slide it right out...  Assuming the corrosion breaks easily.

Comment: Dude, you’re the best. I can’t believe you answered this so quickly and calculated. I will get back to you if I am able to tackle this. Thank you so much!